# Yammer API limits

Tags: api, rest, limit, yammer

Yammer rest api documentation says that limit is 10 requests in 10 seconds per user per app.

Question: What is the *user* here? Is it IP address that makes request or bearer token for currently authenticated yammer user?

If all our users go through same external IP, will this be a problem, or user relates to Yammer user?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is per user token and not by IP Address. So, multiple users from the same IP can make API requests to Yammer and the rate limiting will apply per user. https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/rest-api-rate-limits